# How can I initialize `libdc1394` on Docker

Tags: macos, docker, openalpr

I'm having an error with Docker `libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394`.
I'm following the tutorial to run [openalpr on Docker (bottom of the page)](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr).

```
tmp $curl -O http://plates.openalpr.com/h786poj.jpg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 62721  100 62721    0     0  91248      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 91164
tmp $ls
Atom Crashes            ctr-105095629           ctr-503179909           h786poj.jpg
com.apple.launchd.0ukBh0eylN    ctr-216276841           ctr-689085399
com.apple.launchd.KkrRGe2BZO    ctr-379945785           ctr-860639129
tmp $docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data:ro openalpr -c eu h786poj.jpg
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Image file not found: h786poj.jpg
```

How can I initialize `libdc1394` on Docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You add `-v /dev/null:/dev/raw1394` to docker - Seem's this fixes your problem

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data:ro -v /dev/null:/dev/raw1394 openalpr -c eu   h786poj.jpg
```